# Passing a 2D array from one JavaScript function to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I trying to collect information from the user based on a 2D array. I have problems passing on the 2D array from one function in Javascript to another function, as an array and not as text. What could I be doing wrong?

The array is this

```
Title       Category1   Category2   Category3
Category1   Apples      Blue        Eyes
Category2   Oranges     Green       Legs
Category3   Pairs       Yellow      Arms
            Mango       Gray
```

The idea is to display `Column1` first by having the "Title" as text and the Category list by buttons. On click of a button it should display the contents of the respected column. If, therefore, the user clicks on Category3, he should see Category3 as text and the options "Eyes", "Legs", "Arms" as buttons.

My problem is passing on the `onclick` the correct parameters as `nextStep(this,database)` is not working. When I pass on `nextStep(this,\''+database+'\')` of course it passes on the "database" as text and not as an array.

Any suggestions?

My HTML is a simple div.

```
      <div id="mainPage"></div>
```

My Javascript starts on load...

```
window.addEventListener("load", starting, false);

function starting(){
  var database = [[Title, Category1, Category2, Category3], [Category1,Apples,Blue,Eyes],[Category2,Oranges,Green,Legs],[Category3,Pairs,Yellow,Arms],[,Mango,Gray,]];
  renderCategories(database,1);
}

function renderCategories(database, pos){
  mainPage = document.getElementById("mainPage");

  var catTitles = database[0];
  var catTitle = catTitles[pos];
  var allmainPage = database[2];
  mainPage.innerHTML = '<div class="input-field col s12 m12"><h3>'+catTitle+'</h3></div>';

  for(var i=0; i<allmainPage.length; i++){
    var categoryListValue = allmainPage[i][pos];
    if (categoryListValue !=""){
      mainPage.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><button onclick="nextStep(this,database)" value="'+categoryListValue+'">'+categoryListValue+'</button></div>';
    }
  }
}

function nextStep(selection, database){
  var selectedCat = selection.value;
  alert(selectedCat);
  var catTitles = database[0];
  alert(catTitles);
}
window.addEventListener("load", starting, false);
```

Comment: suggestion: do not use obstrusive listeners directly on html like you are doing with `onclick="..."`, you have much more control over the element and its listener if you create the element (`elem = document.createElement('div')`) and then assign the listener with JS, like: `elem.onclick = ...`

Comment: ```allmainPage``` is one dimensional, you are treating it as if it had two dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you pass the database using the `JSON.stringify()` function, and then you can convert it back using the `JSON.parse()`, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<allmainPage.length; i++){
    let categoryListValue = allmainPage[i][pos],
        databaseString = JSON.stringify(database);

    if (categoryListValue !="")
       mainPage.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><button onclick="nextStep(this,' + databaseString + ')" value="'+categoryListValue+'">'+categoryListValue+'</button></div>';
  }
```

And then:

```
function nextStep(databaseString) {
    let database = JSON.parse(databaseString)
}
```

Although I don't think this is the best way of doing it, it should fix your problem.

If you want my opinion, I think you should store the database in your localstorage and acess it using 'keys' as parameters (like database01) and such.

Comment: Thank you for the note. You are right, I should change the whole thing to do all calculations locally.

Comment: @senedot if you could please accept the answer, I'd be very happy ^^ (Just click the 'check' icon below the updoot/downdoot button)

Comment: Sorry, I am still trying to find my way round here. Thanks for the note and your feedback I really appreciate it.